# Ошибка invalid classname

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр, google-play-services, google-play-console

Всем привет! При настройки игры с google play в unity возникла такая ошибка (на скрине видно). В гугле нашел, что ошибка связана с xml файлом. Однако почему она появляется и как ее решить в контексте настройки плагина я ничего не нашел. Может кто в курсе, как решить данную проблему?

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Приведите пример вашего кода, мы не будем гадать что у вас происходит в `Line 1, position 1.`

Comment: @Anamnian, Проблема не в моем коде а в плагине google play services. Я когда ввел OAuth2 игры а затем нажимаю setup и в этот момент ошибка появляется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас поле ресурсов пустое, вот оно и ругается.

1. Зайдите в Google Play Console.
2. Зайдите в настройки ачивок.
3. Если там нет их ещё, добавьте хоть какую-нибудь тестовую.
4. Нажмите кнопку **Get resources**, полученный xml вставьте в этом окне в поле **Resources Definition**.

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось. Однако странно получается, я не планировал в игру добавлять достижения и рейтинги, и решел что логично будет не добавлять эти ресурсы. А оно получается, что без этих ресурсов игру не привязать к google play и нужно создавать пустышку - ачивку, чтобы получить ресурсы и их добавить в игру.

Comment: @ЕвгенийДанильченко про ачивку-пустышку не уверен, просто я так делал в своё время. Возможно там пустого xml достаточно.